# How do I trace back the shortest path found in a Binary Matrix using a BFS algorithm

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, search, breadth-first-search

So I've implemented a BFS algorithm and I can successfully get the amount of steps it took in order to get from `A -> B` where `A` is the top left most coordinate, and `B` is the bottom left most coordinate.

In my Grid Binary Matrix I have 2 different values.

`0` which is "Traversable".

`1` which is "Non Traversable"

And in my `Visited` grid I also change values that I've visited to `2`. I was going to try to use the `2` to show the path I took by looking up the coordinate of each value that was `2` but that would only show me everything that I've visited and not the shortest path.

Take this grid for instance

```
int[][] grid = new[]
{
    new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0},
    new int[] { 1, 1, 0, 0},
    new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0},
    new int[] { 1, 1, 0, 0}
};
```

There are two paths which can be built which are considered the shortest

[image]
[image]

Either way, the result is `5` which my implementation prints out.

I want to print out the actual path it found, for instance, if the algorithm were to take the path shows in the first image, it would print out `0,0 - 0,1 - 1,2 - 2,2 - 3,3`.

I'm thinking that I need to keep track of the parent node every time I visit a node, in order to know where I came from, but I'm not sure how I would do that.

Here's my implementation

```
int[][] dirs = new[]
{
    new[] { 0, 1 }, //Bottom
    new[] { 1, 1 }, //Bottom right
    new[] { 1, 0 }, //Right
    new[] { 1, -1 }, //Top right
    new[] { 0, -1 }, //Top
    new[] { -1, -1 }, //Top left
    new[] { -1, 0 }, //Left
    new[] { -1, 1 } //Bottom left
};

public int BinaryMatrix(int[][] grid)
{
    /* Length of the rows */
    var rowLength = grid.Length;

    /* The length of each col */
    var colLength = grid[0].Length;

    /* Can't find a path */
    if (grid[0][0] == 1 || grid[rowLength - 1][colLength - 1] == 1)
        return -1;

    var Queue = new Queue<int[]>(); /* Coordinates */

    /* Make a copy of the grid on order to update and perform checks without manipulating the original one. */
    int[][] visited = new int[rowLength][];
    for (int i = 0; i < visited.Length; i++)
        visited[i] = new int[colLength];

    Queue.Enqueue(new[] { 0, 0 });
    visited[0][0] = 2;
    int steps = 1;

    while (Queue.Count != 0)
    {
        int levelSize = Queue.Count;
        for (int r = 0; r < levelSize; r++)
        {
            int[] coord = Queue.Dequeue();

            var cy = coord[0]; /* Y */
            var cx = coord[1]; /* X */

            /* If what we just popped has the same coordinates as the destination */
            if (cy == rowLength - 1 && cx == colLength - 1)
            {
                /* Traceback */
                return steps;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
            {
                int neighborY = dirs[i][0] + cy;
                int neighborX = dirs[i][1] + cx;
                
                /* Bounds check */
                if (neighborX >= 0 && neighborX < colLength && neighborY >= 0 && neighborY < rowLength)
                {
                    /* Visited check */
                    if (visited[neighborY][neighborX] == 0 && grid[neighborY][neighborX] == 0)
                    {
                        Queue.Enqueue(new[] { neighborY, neighborX });
                        visited[neighborY][neighborX] = 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        /* Increment once we're done traversing through a level */
        steps++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Long story short: create `int previousCell[n][m][2]` and record your current cell location when you add new cell to the queue. Sorta place `previousCell[neighborY][neighborX] = {cy, cx}` where `Queue.Enqueue` happens and then trace back from the final cell.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the "visited"-array to keep track of the source node. You could for example store `visited[neighborY][neighborX] = i + 2` to keep track of the direction, and then traverse the tree in reverse to build a list of nodes.

Note that I would really recommend creating a `Vector2i` (i.e. a pair of int) data type to manage coordinates instead of arrays, that should give shorter and easier to understand code. I would also consider using multidimensional arrays, i.e. `int[,]` instead of jagged, `int[][]`.

Another approach would be to use a `Queue<(Vector2i Coordinate, Vector2i[] Path)>` to store the paths explicitly. That would require more memory, but for small data sets the memory usage should be irrelevant.